# Azure AD B2C: Can the password reset verification code expire time be changed and where?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I'm using Azure AD B2C custom policies. Can the password reset verification code expire time be changed and where? Has the default expire time been documented somewhere because I can’t find it. It seems to be 5min.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, expiration time for the OTP code can be configured in the custom policies.
To achieve this, you have to use [Verification display control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/display-control-verification) and modify [GenerateCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/one-time-password-technical-profile#example) technical profile. You have to modify **CodeExpirationInSeconds** metadata item:

```
    <TechnicalProfile Id="GenerateOtp">
      <DisplayName>Generate one time password</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.OneTimePasswordProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="Operation">GenerateCode</Item>
        <Item Key="CodeExpirationInSeconds">120</Item>
        <Item Key="CodeLength">6</Item>
        <Item Key="CharacterSet">0-9</Item>
        <Item Key="NumRetryAttempts">2</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="identifier" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otp" PartnerClaimType="otpGenerated" />
      </OutputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
```